# Side menu is not being shown when push

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I cannot see the side menu when I have used `push`.But it is working fine on `setRoot` navigation.So how can I fix this issue? In other words, I need to show side menu when I used the `push` method.

*dashboard.html*

```
 <ion-col col-9>
  <ion-searchbar (click)="searchPage()" placeholder="Search for Media"></ion-searchbar>
 </ion-col>
```

*dashboard.ts*

```
 searchPage() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('SearchPage');//I can see side menu 
    //this.navCtrl.push('SearchPage');//I cannot see side menu 
  }
```

*search.html*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="secondary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle right>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Just saw this question, your answer is the proper way to address this issue.

Comment: Actually, I got the answer from you using above link. I have accepted the destiny of this question as Duplicate :) @sebaferreras

Comment: Hope you're very busy these days no? We cannot see new answers from you.Are you reading Josh's new book? :) @sebaferreras

Answer (score 1):

I have found the method. **i.e.** need to use `persistent="true"` as shown below.

> persistent    boolean If true, the menu will persist on child pages.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">

</ion-menu>
```